# How to check the physical status of an ethernet port in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I want to check if a specified ethX is physically up or down. How do I do that with the command line?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`$ ethtool <eth?>`

For example:

```
$ ethtool eth0
```

provides:

```
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000001 (1)
        Link detected: yes
```

Answer (score 59):

Check `/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate` and other files in this directory.

As far as I know this is specific to Linux 2.6+, but it provides a clean interface to the kernel driver.

Full documentation for this part of the `sys` file system can be found here:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net

Comment: /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier was the perfect answer to this question for me.

Comment: Great answer. A small addendum: /run/network/ifstate have some useful information too.

Answer (score 37):

`ethtool [interface]`

last line shows what you want:

```
# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000037 (55)
        Link detected: yes
```

Comment: If you check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model . You will see that the last line is about another layer: the link layer. I just tested this. With a bad cable the physical layer was up, but not the link layer. Then I switched to another cable and all layers came up.

Answer (score 28):

```
ip link show
```

is another. Good old

```
ifconfig dev_name
```

or

```
ifconfig -a
```

will also tell you if the interface is up. *NOTE:* Use caution with these methods since they can show out of date information regarding the link's state.

Comment: I think this was the best answer - ethtool isn't standard in my Ubuntu distibution, so it doesn't help if on a box not connected to the net.

Comment: I believe ifconfig will sometimes show out of date data.  It can show UP when the link is down, but ethtool interface will always show the right info AFAIK.

Comment: I think @sed_and_done is right. On a Red Hat VM, if I disconnect the NIC, ethtool immediately shows `Link detected: no` instead of `Link detected: yes`, and **ip link show** shows `<NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>` instead of `<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>`, but **ifconfig -a** shows `UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1`, which is the same as when the NIC is connected.

Answer (score 19):

```
dmesg | grep eth
```

you should see all statuschanges

Comment: This is the only one that works if one lacks admin privileges.

Comment: dmesg requires root on Slackware 14.0

Comment: No, it doesn't. I just checked — while it works for me on `eth0` device, but it doesn't on `eth2` device.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use mii-tool to see if the link is up and check the negotiated speed.

> # mii-tool 
>   eth0: negotiated 100baseTx-FD, link ok

Comment: mii-tool is deprecated and does not work for GbE interfaces.

Comment: @DaveCheney `# mii-tool
eth0: negotiated 1000baseT-FD flow-control, link ok`

Comment: The man page for mii-tool suggests using ethtool. However, mii-tool keeps doing its job, more useful if given the -v (verbose) option.

Answer (score 8):

To quickly add to @[goo](https://serverfault.com/users/5392/goo)'s answer, you would interpret the `ip link` or `ip link show INTERFACE` as follows.

This is a port which is administratively up, but physically down:

`2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000`

In other words, the `UP` you can see indicates the system is configured to try and use the NIC for networking. The `NO-CARRIER` here tells you what the issue preventing networking from working is.

This is a port that is administratively down (its physical layer is 'up', technically - it is a VM):

`3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000`

Finally, this port is working normally:

`2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000`

It is administratively `UP`, the `LOWER_UP` indicates the physical layer is working (i.e. there is a carrier), and the second `UP` confirms (in effect) the IP layer is up.

Comment: Nice Explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can have full details with below command

```
ethtool eth0
```

And if you just want to see link status the give below command

```
mii-tool eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

netplugd is a service that can run program(s) when a cable is plugged in or a cable taken out.  So the command line would be to grep /var/log/messages or dmesg for netplugd output.

Comment: Well, not exactly the requested answer, but an interesting one to know. At least for me.

Answer (score 2):

If your system is using [`ifplugd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifplugd) (e.g. on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian) then you can use the associated status tool `ifplugstatus` to obtain the link status of all interfaces:

```
ifplugstatus
```

or a specific interface (e.g. eth0):

```
ifplugstatus eth0
```